# Finding All Combinations (Cartesian product) of JavaScript array values and then ordering them

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have an array of arrays

```js
allArrays = [
    ['women', 'men'], // gender
    ['age 18-24', 'age 25-34', 'age 35-44', 'age 45 or over'] // age
]
```

Further, I want the order of these arrays to be randomized. [I shuffle the arrays using Fisher-Yates Shuffle from this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/10952717)

```js
// shuffle array of arrays
function shuffle(array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle.
  while (currentIndex != 0) {

    // Pick a remaining element.
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
  }

  return array;
}
    
shuffle(allArrays)
```

Lastly, I want all the combinations of values. [I combine the arrays using the recursive method this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4331218/10952717)

```js
// get all combinations
function allPossibleCases(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 1) {
    return arr[0];
  } else {
    var result = [];
    var allCasesOfRest = allPossibleCases(arr.slice(1)); // recur with the rest of array
    for (var i = 0; i < allCasesOfRest.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
        result.push(arr[0][j] + ", " + allCasesOfRest[i]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

}

let output = allPossibleCases(allArrays)
```

However because the order of the initial arrays is randomized the `output` is either arranged first by gender or first age. i.e., `'women, age 18-24', 'women, age 25-34', 'women age 35-44', ...` or `'age 18-24, women', 'age 18-24, men', 'age 25-34, women', 'age 25-34, men', ...`

The reordering of the string is the intended behavior. However, I am wondering if it is then possible to then arrange the `output` array so that the same gender/age are presented in the same position regardless of their initial shuffle. Ideally, the answer would work for `n` arrays where `n > 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort by age and male/female.

```js
let output = ["age 18-24, women", "age 25-34, women", "age 35-44, women", "age 45 or over, women", "age 18-24, men", "age 25-34, men", "age 35-44, men", "age 45 or over, men"]

const getAge = (str) => {
  let ageArr = str.match(/(age \d)\w/);

  return ageArr?.length ? +ageArr[0].replace("age ", "") : 0;
};

output.sort((a, b) => {
  let age1 = getAge(a);
  let age2 = getAge(b);
  let isFemale1 = a.includes("women");
  let isFemale2 = b.includes("women");

  if (!isFemale1 && isFemale2) {
    return 1
  } else if (isFemale1 && !isFemale2) {
    return -1
  }
  
  return age1 - age2;
});

console.log(output);
```